# Confidence Intervals on Predicted Values

Tags: mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, prediction

Here is a distillation of the problem:

There are 100,000 trials. On each trial, a model predicts a number between 0 and 6.

The model that makes these predictions has been shown to be 90% accurate on each prediction.

The model predicts 3,000 instances of the number "4" throughout the 100,000 trials.

What is the 95% confidence interval around that prediction of 3,000 instances of the number "4"?

Comment: What is your confidence interval supposed to indicate? The number of correct predictions out of 3,000? Incorrect predictions?  Total number of 4's across all trials? etc ...

Comment: It's hard to see how one could provide a definite answer, because "90% accurate" doesn't supply enough information.  For instance, what if in 30,000 of the trials the true value was "3" but 10% of the time a "3" is predicted to be a "4"? That would suggest *every one* of the 3,000 instances of "4" in the trials was an error. Conversely, suppose that the *only* errors the model makes is sometimes to predict "5" when the true value is "4." In that case there could have been up to 13,000 instances of "4" in the trials.